# Discord JDA can't create Role

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am currently coding a Discord bot in Java using the Discord JDA by dv8tion.
There I have a huge problem with creating roles on a guild. When I then try to create a role it gets stuck and doesn't create the role but there are no errors. I have tried using two different methods of creating the role. The first one:

```
Guild g = bot.getGuildById(816744384925663275L);
Role rle;
try {
    rle = g.createRole().setName("Owner").submit().get();
    rle.getManager().setColor(Color.red).queue();
    rle.getManager().setHoisted(true).queue();
    rle.getManager().setMentionable(false).queue();
    rle.getManager().setPermissions(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR).queue();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and the second one:

```
Guild g = bot.getGuildById(816744384925663275L);
Role rle = g.createRole().setName("Owner").complete();
    rle.getManager().setColor(Color.red).queue();
    rle.getManager().setHoisted(true).queue();
    rle.getManager().setMentionable(false).queue();
    rle.getManager().setPermissions(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR).queue();
```

By printing something in the console after every line of code I notices that it gets stuck after the line with g.createRole() in it. I don't know what is going on there or if it is a bug by the JDA.
I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this to create a role:

```java
guild.createRole()
  .setName("Owner")
  .setColor(Color.red)
  .setHoisted(true)
  .setMentionable(false)
  .setPermissions(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR)
  .queue(role -> {
    System.out.println("Created role");
  });
```

If this doesn't work there are three possible reasons:

1. `createRole` threw an exception (use try/catch)
2. `queue()` failed because of a connection or discord error (make sure JDA logs are not turned off)
3. Your code doesn't run (use a debugger)

You should always try setting all fields and calling queue once. In your code with `getManager`, you send edit requests for every single change which is completely unnecessary since the manager can update multiple fields at once, by calling `queue()` only after setting all changes. Calling queue for each setter will only make the updates slower due to rate limits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer although the error was made by the dv8tion JDA. It is now working.